# Working with Photoshop paths

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Can I copy paths from one document to another using Photoshop, If not suggest me the best approach to copy paths through multiple documents.
Thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can copy Paths from one document to another. The process is the same as any other element in a Photoshop document.

Select path
Ctrl+C (Copy)
Ctrl+N (New Document)
Ctrl+V (Paste)